# How does +x in an arrow function returns an array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I saw someone wrote an arrow function in a way that I have never seen before.

```
function reverseArr(num) {
return String(num)
.split("")
.reverse()
.map(x => +x);
}

console.log(reverseArr(1234)); // [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

What does the +x do to the array? When I removed the + sign, I got an array of string instead.

```
// ["4", "3", "2", "1"]
```

Comment: It doesn't nothing to the **array**, `map` runs a function against each member of the array. The `+` operator isn't applied to the array itself.

Comment: split("") will return array of string and +x will be converted to number

Comment: It's a Unary Operator which convert string to a number. https://jsbin.com/rujoforagu/edit?js,console

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I was wrong.  I edited.